# Install cytoolz without gcc

Tags: python, python-3.x, gcc, pip

Is it possible to install cytoolz without gcc? Cytoolz requires gcc to be installed, however, we have a server that is not allowed to have gcc installed.

Python -V = 3.6.4

Comment: _Is it possible to install cytoolz without gcc?_ ....... _Cytoolz requires gcc to be installed_ What kind of solution are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it at a computer with the same platform (processor architecture, 32/64-bitness, OS version) as the server (or an equivalent virtual machine) where you're allowed to install a compiler and build tools. Install the same Python version, install `pip` and run

```
pip wheel cytoolz
```

`pip` downloads `cytoolz` and dependencies and builds binary wheels. Upload those wheels from the current directory to the server and run there

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=. cytoolz-*.whl
```